# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.sqlalchemy

Tags: python, deployment, amazon-ec2, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am deploying my flask app to EC2, however i get the error in my error.log file once i visit the link of my app.
My extensions are present in the site-packages of my flask environment and not the "usr" folder of the server, however it tries to search usr folder to find the hook

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module

It is located in

> /var/www/sample/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages

How to get over this issue?

Comment: Have you tried importing module directly from directory in which it is stored?

Comment: It looks like you are using the system `python` rather than the one inside your virtual environment. What does your server configuration look like?

Comment: got it resolved.. had to make the apache server pick up local flask python exe.. thanks for the comments

Comment: @NandanK Hi Nandan, I am facing the same issue like you. I deployed my flask application on AWS ec2. It shows me the same error. Could you please advise how you fix this issue for the specific details? How your apache server pick up the python from the virtual environment?

Comment: @NandanK by the way, I do have the virtualenv installed and it works good before. Recently I installed the sqlalchemy extension to the local virtualenv and it throws me the issue now.

Comment: @NandanK Hey, never mind my question, I figure it out. Just modify my wsgi script to point to the virtualenv. but still thank you for your post. My website http://52.11.53.125/ from Amazon EC2. still building it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be building your python apps in a virtualenv rather than using the system's installation of python.  Try creating a virtualenv for your app and installing all of the extensions in there.

Comment: got it resolved.. had to make the apache server pick up local flask python exe.. thanks for the comments